# Fastest way to use big numbers

Tags: algorithm, biginteger

Is there any way to reasonably operate on very big integer numbers (millions or billions of digits)? The operations I would need to do are simple +, -, * and maybe /.

What I am looking for are algorithms to do the above operations in a reasonable time (say up to 1 hour on a modern PC). I don't mind using any type of representation for the numbers, but if I need a different representation for each operation, then conversion between the different representations should also be done in reasonable time.

All the big number libraries I have looked at completely break down when used for this size numbers. Is this a sign that no such algorithms exist, or just that these libraries representations/implementations are not optimized for such sizes?

**EDIT** The 1-hour limit is probably impossible. I gave that number since a simple loop over a billion iterations should take less than that, and I was hoping for an algorithm that would use O(n) time. Does a limit of 24-hours seem more reasonable?

Comment: One possibility is doing them the way you learn to do it "by hand" in school, working one digit at a time. Division might be a bit tricky, but the others should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: what about using `N` notation? or divide each side minimized and when the value is at its min such `102^2` or something do the calculation, them maximized again

Comment: @Geobits Doing multiplication "by hand" is n*n 1-digit multiplications and then 2*n*n additions

Comment: A billion decimal digits means about 3 GB of memory in an optimal encoding (most big num libraries use at least a few percent more, for good reasons). Can your computer even store two such numbers?

Comment: @baruch Or it's n*n trips to a lookup table.(and another for the addition, but my point is you don't have to do the math each time)

Comment: @baruch Either way, it's quadratic = completely impractical for numbers of such magnitude.

Comment: The difficulty of getting your numbers in/out of your computer after you have performed the calculation seems to be a significant issue.
Makes me wonder: why do you need to perform these calculations?

Comment: Seriously, as a maths grad I can't see any reason why you need accurate results to calculations of this magnitude.  Have we missed something here - is an approximation to your answer acceptable?  Are you checking for simpler properties, such as divisibility?  Or did Google bully you into doing their homework for them?

Comment: @delnan Are you sure? I came up with only needing 400MiB or so

Comment: To all those wondering about the use: In practice I needed numbers that were 3 or 4 orders of magnitude smaller, but was curious if the tools existed to handle numbers like those mentioned

Comment: @baruch You're right, I arrived at 3 billion *bits*, not bytes.

Comment: How do you get such a big number? Which power of 2 would that be?

Comment: @baruch: On computer you can process several digits at once. Nothing stops you from using multiplication table that goes up to 10000x10000

Comment: On modern machine, addition and substraction of 4000000000 integers should take a minute or less. For those operations you don't have to load entire number into memory and can simply stream it. The problem is multiplication and division. Full multiplication for two 4000000000 numbers can take insane amount of time (you can reduce amount of time by using larger multiplication tables, though). Why do you need precise calculations for such large numbers?

Comment: Suggestion: Possible solution: build a computer cluster, parallelize calculations for multiplication and use very large multiplication tables. The longest operation is multiplication that has complexity of n^2 additions. By increasing size of multiplication table to, say, 100000x100000, you can reduce that time to `(n/log10(table_size))^2`. Which is not much. By increasing number of cores, you can reduce time further down to `(n/(log10(table_size)*num_cores))^2`. Which still isn't that much. You really should think why do you need this kind of precision.

Comment: Did you at least do your Wikipedia [due diligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fast_multiplication_algorithms_for_large_inputs)?

Comment: Actually wikipedia article (linked by mbeckish) provides "karatsuba multiplication" algorithm. Good news: It is O(n^1.585). Bad news: it'll still take 200+ days to multiply 2 billion-digit numbers on modern hardware without parallelization. Good news - it is 200 days, and not 7000 years (as with long multiplication).

Comment: I would probably look into using FFT to do multiplication, and implement it on CUDA.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to take a look at the [DecInt Python class](http://home.comcast.net/~casevh/).

This is optimised for very long decimal integers.  (The numbers are stored in a representation that makes it easy to convert to decimal digits in O(n) time).

It can do the operations you wish including:

1. Multiplication in O(n ln(n))
2. Division in O(n ln(n)^2)

Comment: I will look at it later tonight

Comment: On later versions of Python do a search and replace of "as" to "as2".  (Because "as" has become a reserved keyword)